# why edit action try to save nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a models like Routine and RoutineContent for localization

in Routine.rb

```
Class Routine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :routine_contents, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :routine_contents, reject_if: proc {|attributes| attributes['title'].empty?}
end
```

and in RoutinesContent

```
class RoutineContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :routine
  validates_presence_of :title
end
```

In the new Routine action I puts on RoutineConten fields for languages. If title in one object is emty then this object will rejected.

When I go to edit action, I do this

```
def set_routine_contents
    contents = @routine.routine_contents.group_by {|content| content.lang}
    if contents['ru'].nil?
      @routine.routine_contents << RoutineContent.new(lang: 'ru')
    end
    if contents['en'].nil?
      @routine.routine_contents << RoutineContent.new(lang: 'en')
    end
end
```

end after this Rails INSERT INTO emty object in table, why? How I can disable it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
def set_routine_contents
    contents = @routine.routine_contents.group_by {|content| content.lang}
    if contents['ru'].nil?
      @routine.routine_contents.build(lang: 'ru')
    end
    if contents['en'].nil?
      @routine.routine_contents.build(lang: 'en')
    end
end
```

Use the build method. Add to Array via << it was bad idea

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` association implemented with foreign key in `routine_id` in `routine_contents` table.

So adding new RoutineContent to your Routine requires determined primary key in Routine to write to `routine_id`, and causes Routine to save if not saved yet.